# Problem with Python Games

Tags: python

Having eagerly ripped open my newly arrived toy, I've just installed the Raspbian Wheezy image & am impressed that it really does just boot and appears to work - however, the Python Games that come with it - whenever a game starts it says "press a key to start" and when I press a key it drops back to the menu of games again - does anyone know what I might be doing wrong please!

Comment: What games package is this? I didn't know wheezy came with games.

Comment: @Jivings Wheezy comes with a package of Python games, with a link placed on the desktop. (AFAIK)

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is rather old maybe there are others still interested in an answer.

As @Chris stated the problems could be related to missing packages. To test this you could start the game in a terminal. Therefore open up a terminal:

```
cd /home/pi/python_games
python <game>.py # where `<game>` is the game you want to start!
```

If there are really missing packages you should now be able to read an error message pointing to it. Knowing the missing package name you can use `apt-get` to install it. Start over again and install every missing package until the game finally starts.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Python Games is a desktop option installed as apart of the default image - however, cracked the problem - some of the packages weren't installed initially, for the life of me I can't remember which as I've been fighting usb issues ever since.